# Apache Ignite, C#/.NET: BinaryObject Warning - Execpted and Actual ValueType not equal, unable to query entries

Tags: c#, ignite

I was trying to store BinaryObjects in cache, specifically following this [example](https://github.com/apache/ignite/blob/master/modules/platforms/dotnet/examples/Apache.Ignite.Examples/Datagrid/BinaryModeExample.cs). However, while the cache is getting populated, I am unable to SQL queries on the entries.

While I am getting an output of `>>> BinaryObject.cs - Person: Cache Loaded. Size: 10`, I am also getting warnings of the following:

```
[12:45:33,939][WARNING][main][GridQueryProcessor] Key-value pair is not inserted into any SQL table [cacheName=default, expValType=BinaryObject.Student, actualValType=Student]
[12:45:33,940][WARNING][main][GridQueryProcessor]   ^-- Value type(s) are specified via CacheConfiguration.indexedTypes or CacheConfiguration.queryEntities
[12:45:33,947][WARNING][main][GridQueryProcessor]   ^-- Make sure that same type(s) used when adding Object or BinaryObject to cache
[12:45:33,953][WARNING][main][GridQueryProcessor]   ^-- Otherwise, entries will be stored in cache, but not appear as SQL Table rows
```

And this is definitely the reason why I don't see an output on my SQL query:

```
>>> All person names:
```

I have the following code:

**Program.cs**

```
namespace BinaryObject
{
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            var cfg = new IgniteConfiguration
            {
                // TCPDiscoverySpi Configuration
            };

            using (IIgnite ignite = Ignition.Start(cfg))
            {
                // Establish database connection; query database
                DBConnection dbc = new DBConnection();
                OracleConnection con = dbc.EstablishConnection();
                OracleCommand cmd = dbc.CreateCommand(con, "SELECT * FROM STUDENT WHERE ROWNUM <= 10");
                OracleDataReader reader = dbc.DatabaseReader(cmd);

                var cache0 = ignite.GetOrCreateCache<object, object>(new CacheConfiguration
                {
                    Name = "default",
                    Backups = 1,
                    QueryEntities = new[]
                    {
                        new QueryEntity(typeof(int), typeof(Student))
                    }
                });

                var cache = cache0.WithKeepBinary<int, IBinaryObject>();
                
                cache.Clear();

                IBinary binary = cache.Ignite.GetBinary();

                while (reader.Read())
                {
                    Student.SetStudentObject(reader, binary, cache);
                }

                Console.WriteLine();
                Console.WriteLine(">>> Binary Object - Student: Cache Loaded. Size: " + cache.GetSize() );
                Console.WriteLine();
                SqlQueryExample(cache);
            }
        }

        private static void SqlQueryExample(ICache<int, IBinaryObject> cache)
        {
            var qry = cache.Query(new SqlFieldsQuery("select FirstName from Student"));

            Console.WriteLine();
            Console.WriteLine(">>> All student names:");

            foreach (var row in qry)
                Console.WriteLine(">>>     " + row[0]);
        }
    }
}
```

**Student.cs**

```
namespace BinaryObject
{
    class Student
    {
        [QuerySqlField(IsIndexed = true)]
        public int StudentId { get; set; }
        [QuerySqlField]
        public string FirstName { get; set; }
        [QuerySqlField]
        public string LastName { get; set; }
        [QuerySqlField]
        public string Major { get; set; }

        public void SetStudentObject(OracleDataReader reader)
        {
            cache[reader.IsDBNull(0) ? 0 : reader.GetInt32(0)] = binary.GetBuilder("Student")
                .SetField("Student", reader.IsDBNull(0) ? 0 : reader.GetInt32(0))
                .SetField("FirstName", reader.IsDBNull(5) ? "" : reader.GetString(5))
                .SetField("LastName", reader.IsDBNull(2) ? "" : reader.GetString(2))
                .SetField("Major", reader.IsDBNull(1) ? "" : reader.GetString(1))
                .Build();
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 3):

See the error message: `expValType=BinaryObject.Student, actualValType=Student`. You have to use the full type name when creating a binary object.

Replace `binary.GetBuilder("Student")` with `binary.GetBuilder("BinaryObject.Student")`.

Comment: Or enable simple class name mapper!